# ¿ Como puedo obtener la ruta de un archivo en java?

Tags: java, java-ee

estoy tratado de obtener la ruta donde esta almacenado un archivo, es decir.
File archivo1 = new File("C:\Usuario\Unigo\Desktop\Carpeta\texto1.txt");
File archivo2 = new File("D:\Carpeta\texto2.txt");

Salida:
El arhivo 1 esta en la unidad C:\
El arhivo 2 esta en la unidad D:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer muy fácilmente separando la cadena en partes (el delimitador es la contrabarra `\`) y quedándote con la primera de las partes.

```
String nombreFichero = "fichero.txt";
```

Supón que tenemos un fichero llamado `fichero.txt`.

```
String rutaAbsoluta = new File(nombreFichero).getAbsolutePath();
```

Lo primero que hacemos es obtener la ruta absoluta del fichero, que será del tipo `C:\algo\fichero.txt`

```
String[] partesRuta = rutaAbsoluta.split("\\");
// partesRuta[0] = "C:"
// partesRuta[1] = "algo"
// partesRuta[2] = "fichero.txt"
```

Esto separa la cadena de texto con la ruta absoluta en varias cadenas, que se corresponden con los directorios hasta llegar al fichero.

De manera interna se utiliza una expresión regular para separar la cadena con el carácter contrabarra `\` como delimitador. Y dado que la contrabarra es un carácter especial, se tiene que poner con una secuencia de escape, es decir, dos veces la contrabarra.

La letra de la unidad a la que pertenece el fichero será la primera de todas las cadenas devueltas.

```
String unidad = partesRuta[0];
```

Esto sirve para sistemas Windows.

Si quisieras hacer algo similar en sistemas Unix (Mac, Linux), el codigo cambia ligeramente, debido a que el separador de directorios es la barra `/`, y que no hay el concepto de unidad, sino de directorio raíz `/`.

```
String nombreFichero = "fichero";
// Ruta del tipo /home/usuario/fichero
String rutaAbsoluta = new File(nombreFichero).getAbsolutePath();
// partesRuta[0] = "";
// partesRuta[1] = "home"
// partesRuta[2] = "usuario"
// partesRuta[3] = "fichero"
String[] partesRuta = rutaAbsoluta.split("/");
// Porque la ruta absoluta empieza con una barra, con lo que el primer directorio aparece en la segunda posición del array
String primerDirectorio = partesRuta.length > 2 ? "/" + partesRuta[1] : "/";
```

La última asignación tiene en cuenta que un fichero cualquiera puede colgar del directorio raíz `/`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvio de mucho tú respuesta :)